# Best way to create a 3D model in C/C#

Tags: c#, 3d

I have a file in .ASC format and it is a DTM (Digital Terrain Model).
It basically consists of a matrix of points, each represented by a value indicating his altitude. I wanna have a 3D model based on this points (it should be a 3D map), but I don't know what to use. I tried WPF, but it seemed not good for the purpose. Then I started looking at OpenGL, but I don't know if it's the right technology or if I need something easier/better. What do you think I need to use?

Comment: This is way too broad. " it seemed not good for the purpose" and "easier/better" are very vague. Please be more specific. What is the problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to manipulate these points and create the 3D model, but I don't want an hard library that does loads of things that I won't use.

Comment: Not quite sure but have you tried Blender? Opensource 3D Modelling Tool that can import a lot of things...

Comment: I need to write my own program that also creates that 3D model

Comment: You can write a Blender Plugin in Python too ... on what basis do you want to create the model?

Comment: I have an ASC file which looks like:
253.66 548.25 259.36 ...
258.36 623.33....
And the numbers are the height of the points

Comment: I would try to import it in Blender... Blender is allready a product that allows to create Models ... if it does not support the format i would rather go and write a converter in Python (even if you have to learn the language) before reinventing the wheel from scratch

Comment: Blender has a huge community too... There might be someone that wrote that converter allready...

Comment: http://www.blender.org/ to save you googleing